# Trying to get the x and y of the scrolled page - no errors

Tags: javascript, scroll, event-handling, mouseevent

Trying to get the x and y of the scrolled page and display the (x,y) in the console.log. The problem: It doesn't display anything in the console and NO errors. Any ideas?

```
// On load listen to the scroll event
window.onload = function() {
 // Get the x and y of the scroll
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
         document.getScroll= function(){
             var sx, sy;
             if(window.pageYOffset!= undefined){
                sx = pageXOffset;
                sy = pageYOffset;

                 console.log(sx +" else " + sy);

              // return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
             }
             else{
               var d= document, r= d.documentElement, b= d.body;
              sx= r.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft || 0;
              sy= r.scrollTop || b.scrollTop || 0;
              console.log(sx +" else " + sy);
              // return [sx, sy];

             }
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `getScroll` ,your code is inside it and you are not calling it:

```js
     window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
              var sx, sy;
              if(window.pageYOffset!= undefined){
                 sx = pageXOffset;
                 sy = pageYOffset;
                  console.log(sx +" else " + sy);
               // return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
              }
              else{
                var d= document, r= d.documentElement, b= d.body;
               sx= r.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft || 0;
               sy= r.scrollTop || b.scrollTop || 0;
               console.log(sx +" else " + sy);
               // return [sx, sy];
              }
     });
```

```html
<body style="height:1500px;">

</body>
```

**OR** call it on scroll.

```js
     window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
          getScroll= function(){//remove document part
              var sx, sy;
              if(window.pageYOffset!= undefined){
                 sx = pageXOffset;
                 sy = pageYOffset;
                  console.log(sx +" else " + sy);
               // return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
              }
              else{
                var d= document, r= d.documentElement, b= d.body;
               sx= r.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft || 0;
               sy= r.scrollTop || b.scrollTop || 0;
               console.log(sx +" else " + sy);
               // return [sx, sy];
              }
         }
          getScroll();//call your function
     });
```

```html
<body style="height:1500px;">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed "document.getScroll= function(){ }" from your code

```
 // Get the x and y of the scroll
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {


             var sx, sy;
             if(window.pageYOffset!= undefined){
                sx = pageXOffset;
                sy = pageYOffset;

                 console.log(sx +" else " + sy);

              // return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
             }
             else{
               var d= document, r= d.documentElement, b= d.body;
              sx= r.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft || 0;
              sy= r.scrollTop || b.scrollTop || 0;
              console.log(sx +" else " + sy);
              // return [sx, sy];

             }

    });

};
```